# Iterating Date variables in List Object and select the date range based on position

Tags: java

I have a situation where I added dates in a `List`. Now, I want to select the first 2 position date as start date and end date and next 2 position as start date and end date so on. After I get the start and end date, I need to find the number of days between the days and calculate the amount for the number of days.

Here are the dates in list object.

`[2018-09-05, 2018-09-14, 2018-09-29, 2018-10-14, 2018-10-29]`

1. `2018-09-05` as startdate and `2018-09-13` as end date - Find number of days between these dates.
2. `2018-09-14` as startdate and `2018-09-28` as end date - Find number of days between these dates.
3. `2018-09-29` as startdate and `2018-10-13` as end date - Find number of days between these dates.
4. `2018-10-14` as startdate and `2018-10-28` as end date - Find number of days between these dates.

Please help me how to find it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: List will maintain the order of elements. You have to make sure that successive element should be greater than the first & less than the next element else your logic will fail. Please show the code what you tried till now

Comment: Your ex has a list with 5 items but you the pairs don't match the list items. Is there something missing?

Comment: @Shriram, I am using TreeSet to dates are sorted in order.

Comment: @forpas, this is correct order. Actually I have to reduce one day from the end date when I do calculate number of days difference.

Comment: @Parthee so if for example the 2 dates are "2018-09-05" and "2018-09-06" my code prints 1. You want it to print 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below code will work if the list contains even number of valid date strings.  
Will iterate the list, extract each pair of dates and calculate the difference in days:

```
public static long getDaysDif(LocalDate fromDate, LocalDate toDate) {
    return ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(fromDate, toDate);
}

public static LocalDate getLocalDateFromString(String d, String format) {
    return LocalDate.parse(d, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(format));
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>
            (Arrays.asList
                    ("2018-09-05", "2018-09-13", "2018-09-14", "2018-09-28", "2018-09-29", "2018-10-13"));
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i+=2) {
        String strStart = list.get(i);
        String strEnd = list.get(i + 1);

        LocalDate dateStart = getLocalDateFromString(strStart, "yyyy-MM-dd");
        LocalDate dateEnd = getLocalDateFromString(strEnd, "yyyy-MM-dd");

        long dif = getDaysDif(dateStart, dateEnd);

        System.out.println(dif);
    }
}
```

will print:

```
8
14
14
```

Comment: You can use the diamond operator.

Comment: Thanks this helps lot.

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand the first part of your question about selecting the dates, but to find the number of days between dates you could do the following:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.Period;

public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LocalDate startDate= LocalDate.now();
        LocalDate endDate= today.plusDays(6);

        Period period = Period.between(startDate, endDate);
        int difference = period.getDays();
    }
}
```